# npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.3.3: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-start

I am totally beginner in React JS. After installing a package named 'Tachyons' with this command `npm install --save-dev tachyons@4.10.0` I am keep getting this error while starting the npm with this command `npm start` in the react project. But the thing is- It was working fine before installing the package. I don't know what's got wrong. Hope someone will help me out. Thanks.

```
npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.3.3: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
npm WARN deprecated kleur@2.0.2: Please upgrade to kleur@3 or migrate to 'ansi-colors' if you prefer the old syntax. Visit <https://github.com/lukeed/kleur/releases/tag/v3.0.0\> for migration path(s).
npm WARN rollback Rolling back @types/node@11.9.5 failed (this is probably harmless): EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\robofriends\node_modules\@types\node'
npm WARN ts-pnp@1.0.1 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! path C:\Users\User\Desktop\robofriends\node_modules\@types
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\robofriends\node_modules\@types'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\robofriends\node_modules\@types']
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\robofriends\node_modules\@types'
npm ERR!      errno: -4048,
npm ERR!      code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!      path:
npm ERR!       'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\robofriends\\node_modules\\@types' },
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    "Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\robofriends\\node_modules\\@types'",
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path:
npm ERR!    'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\robofriends\\node_modules\\@types',
npm ERR!   parent: 'robofriends' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-24T22_26_47_036Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

The log you have is actually quite clear on possible reasons you are getting the error...

> The operation was rejected by your operating system.
>   npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
>   npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.

Do you have another terminal open?

> If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
>   npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
>   npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

Run your command prompt as administrator.

Other than the above, the first 4 lines of the log give you warnings, you should always avoid using an old version of packages or packages that are not being actively maintained.